# Centering a figure in a page with different \textwidth

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page, format, figure-placement

I set up the page geometry to remove margin notes, footer and head so it uses all the available space.
While I managed to center the text in the page now the figure is not centered

```
  \marginparwidth 0pt
  \marginparsep 0pt
  \footskip 0pt
  \headheight 0pt
  \headsep 0pt
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\dimexpr \hmargin -1in}
  \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr \pdfpagewidth -2\oddsidemargin -2in}
  \setlength{\textwidth}{\hsize}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
      \centering
      \def\svgwidth{10em}
      \input{logo.pdf_tex}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{center}
      ...
    \end{center}
```

The figure is not centered now but it is centered to the text when I remove the \hsize definition, making me think there is some kind of nebulous variable which govern the position and it still set as default, but I couldn't find any.

### EDIT

I found out it was caused by the pdf_tex being into a figure instead of a png image. defining `\input{logo.pdf_tex}` outside the figure and in a center enviroinment works perfectly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please extend your code into a programme that can compile please, starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, it helps people troubleshoot and answer your question

Comment: I would suggest to use [package `geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and it's command `\newgeometry` to change the margins inside a document.

Comment: Note that changing the page geometry correctly will force a \clearpage before and after.  It might be easier to simply overlap the margins with a minipage.